# Scraping Tables in Python Using Beautiful Soup AttributeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping the two tables from the webpage: https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/?option=spiele&saison_id=2017&altersklasse=alle

I am trying to get many countries and years of data and have set up lists including country URLs.

Here is my code:

```
for l in range(0, len(league_urls)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #The second loop is for each year we want to scrape
    for n in range(2007,2020):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        df_soccer1 = None
        url = league_urls[l] + str(n) + str('&altersklasse=alle')
        headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        #Table 1 with information about the value
        table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "items"})

        team = []
        players_used = []
        minutes_nonforeign = []
        minutes_foreign = []

        for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            try:
                col = row.find_all('td')
                team_ = col[1].text
                players_used_ = col[2].text
                minutes_nonforeign_ = col[3].text
                minutes_foreign_ = col[4].text
                team.append(team_)
                players_used.append(players_used_)
                minutes_nonforeign.append(minutes_nonforeign_)
                minutes_foreign.append(minutes_foreign_)
            except:
                team.append('')
                players_used.append('')
                minutes_nonforeign.append('')
                minutes_foreign.append('')

        team = [elem.replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','').strip() for elem in team]
        
 #Table 2 with information about placement, goals and points
        df_soccer2 = None

        table2 = soup.find("div", {"class" : "box tab-print"})

        team2 = []
        place = []
        matches = []
        difference = []
        pts = []

        for row in table2.find_all('tr'):
            try:
                col = row.findAll('td')
                team2_ = col[2].text
                place_  = col[0].text
                matches_ = col[3].text
                difference_ = col[4].text
                pts_ = col[5].text
                team2.append(team2_)
                place.append(place_)
                matches.append(matches_)
                difference.append(difference_)
                pts.append(pts_)
            except:
                team2.append('')
                place.append('')
                matches.append('')
                difference.append('')
                pts.append('')
               

        team2 = [elem.replace('\n','').replace('\xa0','').strip() for elem in team2]

        df_soccer1 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': team[1:], 'Season': [n]*(len(team)-1), 'Players used': players_used[1:], 
                                    'Minutes nonforeign': minutes_nonforeign[1:], 'Minutes foreign': minutes_foreign[1:]})
        
        df_soccer2 = pd.DataFrame({'Team': team2, 'Place': place, 'Matches': matches, 'Difference': difference,
                                     'Points': pts})
```

I am getting this issue when scraping the first table:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-b4cd681f68e8> in <module>
     21         minutes_foreign = []
     22 
---> 23         for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
     24             try:
     25                 col = row.find_all('td')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

To note, league_urls is a long list of URLs.

I have used a similar code on another portion of the site and it works great. I just can't seem to figure out why it is not working on this one.

In addition, when I run the code using just a single URL, it works great. Is it possible there is some problem since I am looping across 12 years for 55 different URLs?

Comment: Update: I am guessing the issue is that the loop goes to certain URLs, the table does not exist, but the URL still works. For example, the year 2011 for Russia does not have any data. I think this is causing the issue.

https://www.transfermarkt.com/remier-liga/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/RU1/plus/?option=spiele&saison_id=2011&altersklasse=alle

Any thoughts on creating an exception to put blanks into the dataframe when this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if table is None e.g.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/remier-liga/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/RU1/plus/?option=spiele&saison_id=2011&altersklasse=alle'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
#time.sleep(0.5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#Table 1 with information about the value
table = soup.find("table", {"class" : "items"})

team = []
players_used = []
minutes_nonforeign = []
minutes_foreign = []

if not table is None:
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            try:
                col = row.find_all('td')
                team_ = col[1].text
                players_used_ = col[2].text
                minutes_nonforeign_ = col[3].text
                minutes_foreign_ = col[4].text
                team.append(team_)
                players_used.append(players_used_)
                minutes_nonforeign.append(minutes_nonforeign_)
                minutes_foreign.append(minutes_foreign_)
            except:
                team.append('')
                players_used.append('')
                minutes_nonforeign.append('')
                minutes_foreign.append('')
else:
    team.append('')
    players_used.append('')
    minutes_nonforeign.append('')
    minutes_foreign.append('')
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!